# Limit x tending to 0 exponential problem

Tags: limits

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac {2e^{1/x} - 3x} {e^{1/x} + x} $$
I need to solve this, and I tried to get this in the $$(e^x - 1)\over x$$ form (since x tends to 0, that would make the result equal to 1) but that doesn't seem to be working. Also tried multiplying the numerator and denominator with $e^x$ but that didn't help any either.

Comment: Do you mean $x \to 0^+$ or $0^-$, i.e., a one-sided limit? Otherwise it's not clear the limit exists.

Comment: The answer in the source says 2.

Comment: I'm not sure which side the limit approaches from.

Comment: In which case it is $x \to 0^+$. The $e^{1/x}$ terms dominate, as they go to $+\infty$. So divide top and bottom by $e^{1/x}$, i.e., multiply by $e^{-1/x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:$L_{+} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} Q = 2, L_{-} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} Q = ?$. In this case, let $y = \dfrac{1}{x}$, and find $L_{-} = \displaystyle \lim_{y \to -\infty} \dfrac{2e^y - \dfrac{3}{y}}{e^y+\dfrac{1}{y}}=...=-3$. Thus there is **no** limit.